# Method sendFile Express different if it's html or php

Tags: php, node.js, express

I made a simple form in my HTML file "index.html":

```
<form action="/" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then, I first redirected it to a HTML page which simply say "thank you" in a H1 tag, in my "success.html" file. I did it with Node.js and Express framework, here is my "app.js" file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser=require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/success.html');
})
```

It worked. But when I tried to do a redirection to a PHP page "received.php" in order to display the name and email, here is my "received.php" file:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
```

I change the last line of my "app.js" file `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/success.html');` to  `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/received.php');`

And now I can't see the "received.php" but it directly download the "received.php" when I click on submit button. I find it strange.

How can I display my "received.php" like I did with the "success.html"? I just want to see the name and email.

Comment: Check this out and tell me if it helps apparently res.sendFile is only used to serve statatic files.https://codeforgeek.com/express-res-sendfile/#:~:text=res.sendFile%20%28%29%20Method%20Express%20provides%20a%20method%20in,can%20use%20express.static%20%28%29%20to%20set%20the%20path.

Answer (score 0):

res.sendFile() method accepts absolute paths only. You can use express.static() to set the path.
Create a folder where you are going to store your files and declare it as static

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser=require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(express.static(public));
app.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  
  res.sendFile('/index.html');
})
```

Here's a [reference](https://codeforgeek.com/express-res-sendfile/#:%7E:text=res.sendFile%20%28%29%20Method%20Express%20provides%20a%20method%20in,can%20use%20express.static%20%28%29%20to%20set%20the%20path.) for you